# File.createnewFile() always returns false even if the file is newly created

Tags: java

I am creating a file with the statemnent:

```
"File f1=new File(//some random path)";
f1.mkdirs();
```

To this point it was working fine.

```
try{

    boolean c=f1.createNewFile();

    }

catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println("caught exception");}
     System.out.println(c);
```

It returns `False` every time I execute my code even if the file doesn't exist from before and is newly created in this compilation only.

Answer (score 0):

Because [mkdirs()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) in previous line already created the directory

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories.

And `createNewFile()` will always return `false` because it's already created

> creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with **this name does not yet exist**.

So it's redundant you can satisfied with

```
 boolean c = false; 
 try {
     c = f1.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code compiles, `c` is a field of your class that has value `false`. The local variable in the `try{}` block only exists within the `try{}` block and is forgotton before `System.out.println(c)` is processed.
You are not printing the return value of `c=f1.createNewFile()` from within the try block, but the content of the field `YourClass.c` which was never touched.

If there is no field `c` in your class, your code does not compile.